# Google App Engine, get namespace with python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, namespaces

I'm currently using the Google App Engine with Python. I setup some data in a namespace, and now i'm trying to get that data from a namespace. But i can't get it to work.

When i do this, then it all works fine:

```
namespace_manager.set_namespace('test')
```

But when i do this, then it doesn't work:

```
bla = namespace_manager.get_namespace()
namespace_manager.set_namespace(bla)
```

My URL did point to a namespace: http://test.my-app.appspot.com

But for some reason it doesn't pick up the namespace. Anyone any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a sub-domain, not a namespace. If you want each subdomain to correspond to a namespace, you will need to configure that yourself, by setting the namespace for each request based on the domain name.

Your second snippet will never do anything - it will always set the namespace to what it already is.